# TortoiseGit cherry pick failed! Skip this commit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-cherry-pick

I have the problem using TortoiseGit:

[image]
[image]

Why can this happen while doing fetch and rebase?
The `bundle.js` file is generated by webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the solution. The problem was in Web Pack Task Runner, that started to work after fetch. Then, trying to rebase - TortoiseGit found something else to commit from me. So I have this problem only with `bundle.js` file that was changed during the process Fetch and Rebase.

Answer (score 3):

See the message directly behind the messagebox.

There you can see "nothing to commit". The changes of the commit were already applied to the branch you want to apply this commit to. So, the "right" decision would be to say "Skip" in this case.

PS: In your first screenshot you can also see, that TortoiseGit detected this in advance and pre-selected "skip" for this commit.

Comment: Yes, but there is what to commit. In another option - when I commit this bundle together with other changed fies - TortoisGit skips the whole commit. So I lose my changes.